# How continuously spinning sync() call can cause high IO wait?

Tags: linux

From what I undertstand from `sync()` library call is that it allows a process to flush all dirty buffers to disk

> The service routine sys_sync( ) of the sync( ) system call invokes a
>   series of auxiliary functions:

```
wakeup_bdflush(0);
sync_inodes(0);
sync_supers( );
sync_filesystems(0);
sync_filesystems(1);
sync_inodes(1);
```

If i run `sync()` call once, after that there shouldn't be anything in the buffer.

I am using a tool called `stress` that when runs with `-i` flag **spawn N workers spinning on sync()**,

```
stress --i 1
```

This command suppose to consume high IO wait since it keep sending `sync()` calls,
I confirmed it using `ltrace`,

```
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
sync()                                                                                                               = 0
```

Can someone please explain why continuous sync calls consume a lot of IO? I was assuming that after first sync call buffer should be empty.

Comment: Does it generate real IO, or just processes in D state wait? The latter may be due to internal locking & contention between processes.  I.e., what IO utilization does it show in `iostat` / `iotop` ?

Comment: iostat goes up high and process goes in `D` state just for very tiny second.

Answer (score 0):

sync() is like a database commit but for your disk. (in fact, for transactional databases a commit usually involves a sync() call to help ensure ACID... you have to go out of your way to prevent it)  Rather than going through the normal performance-optimizing channels of the OS, you're telling the OS: 'do this right now!'  With spinning, mechanical disks performance is all about the physics: it takes time for the drive to position the head wherever it needs to be to actually perform the requested operation (and even when it gets there, it has to wait for the disc to spin to the correct position under the head before it can do what it came there to do.)  When you're constantly (or even occasionally) syncing, you're bypassing a lot of opportunities to optimize this work via buffering and scheduling.  Also note that when you call sync() you're doing this for **all pending filesystem writes**, including metadata, not just a single file or filesystem.

So let's look at a simplified scenario where you have a program that needs to write four sectors to the disk: one on the innermost track (w1), one on the outermost track (w2), one on the middle track of the disk (w3), and finally one back on the innermost track (w4)...

If your program writes w1 then calls sync(), your system immediately has the drive perform the write which causes the drive to move all the way to the innermost track and write the sector.  Then w2 occurs followed by a sync(), so now the drive has to go all the way to the outside track to write the sector.  Next w3 occurs and the drive has to move back to the center of the disk and write the sector.  Finally w4 occurs and the drive has to go back to the innermost track and write the sector.  What is the CPU doing all the time the drive head is moving?  Literally waiting.

Had you not made all of those sync() calls, the OS would have buffered all of those writes and immediately returned to the program ('yeah, yeah... I'll get to it eventually') and now it has w1-w4 buffered.  Both the OS and the drive can  schedule the requests in whatever way makes sense, without forcing the drive to write each sector independently or even in order.  So let's say that the OS decided to perform the write after w4 came in, it will send all 4 writes to the drive and the drive can see that w1 and w4 should be performed first (i.e. the innermost track), then it should do w3 (the middle track), and finally w2 (the outermost track).  So instead of 4 separate seeks (which are measured in milliseconds), it's only doing 3.  And each seek is shorter in linear distance, and therefore faster, than in the sync() scenario.  Start multiplying that inefficiency out by hundreds of times or more and you start to see why you're spending all your time waiting when you constantly sync().  Flash drives  have similar scheduling efficiencies (i.e. multiple writes to the same block etc) but they don't have the same order of magnitude of impact that mechanical drives do.